# Android & MoPub - App freeze on startup

Tags: android, freeze, mopub

I'm using a 320x50 banner ad thru MoPub SDK for Android.

**THE PROBLEM**:

Whenever my activity is loading my app hangs/freezes while MoPub attempts to detect a users geographical location. It takes about 5 seconds for MoPub to determine that it cannot detect the user's location.

For the whole 5+ seconds the app user is staring at a blank activity screen.

Once MoPub decide to move on and finish loading an ad anyway, everything works fine.

But in the mobile app world 5 seconds is an eternity.

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**:

I've tried moving the AdView to the `doInBackground()` of a AsyncTask but of course that does not work because background threads cannot touch views on the UI Thread.

I've also tried moving

`moPubView = (MoPubView) findViewById(R.id.adview);`

`moPubView.setAdUnitId("--UNIT ID HERE--");`

`moPubView.setKeywords("--KEYWORDS--");`

and

`moPubView.loadAd();`

to the `postExecute()` method of a AsyncTask (that Im using to load my Activity's data anyway) but this does not work.

**Preferred Outcome**:

How do I prevent MoPub from attempting ANYTHING until I say so?

I would like it to wait about 1-2 seconds before loading anything to give my activity time to do its main tasks.

Comment: Its hard to believe that I'm the only person to ever experience this.

Comment: I have the same issue but on iOS see link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18013603/ios-mopub-app-freezes-when-loading-ad-on-a-slow-network

Comment: any solution plz ?

Comment: There was a solution to edit a file in the mopub sdk library. It was posted by a user on mopub google support forum. I'm sorry but I don't have the link. I haven't used mobup in a while. I'd hope its officially fixed by now.